# Как сделать фоновое выполнение скрипта php на сревере

Tags: php

Как что-бы определенный файл php исполнялся каждый час ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что за странный вопрос? RTFM [PHP Cron Job: How to Execute PHP Script Using Crontab in Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)

Comment: можно еще демона запилить, но демон на php... наверное это не тот язык

Comment: не, тем более для "раз в час" нафиг не надо доп ресурсы сжирать, на хостингах это обычно пагубно сказывается на производительности :)

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука, называется German. Ооочень крутая вещь)

Comment: Вещь крутая, если есть очередь заданий. Если же нужно делать запуск раз в час - пустая трата времени/ресурсов